# Example of modules not determined by their endomorphism rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Given a ring $R$, are all modules over $R$ determined, up to isomorphism, by their endomorphism rings?

I read [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/1245/1/012050/pdf) that if $R$ is a division ring or a simple Artinian ring, this property is true.
Otherwise, what is an example of two modules over R that are not isomorphic, but their endomorphism ring are isomorphic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the group of rational numbers with square-free denominators.

Then, for any endomorphism $f$ of $A$ and any $\frac{a}{b} \in A$, $bf(\frac{a}{b})=f(a)=af(1)$, so $f(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{a}{b}f(1)$. Hence, $f$ is determined by $f(1)$.

Now, suppose that $f(1)=\frac{a}{b}$ (in reduced form) where $b>1$. Then, $f(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{a}{b}f(1)=\frac{a}{b}\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a^2}{b^2} \notin A$ (since $\frac{a^2}{b^2}$ is in reduced form but $b^2$ is not square-free), a contradiction. Hence, $b=1$ and $f(1) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

So, $\mathrm{End}(A) \cong \mathbb{Z} \cong \mathrm{End}(\mathbb{Z})$, but $A \not\cong \mathbb{Z}$. This is an example where $R=\mathbb{Z}$ (since abelian groups are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules).

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "I read here that if R is a division ring or a simple Artinian ring, this property is true.
Otherwise, what is an example of two modules over R that are not isomorphic, but their endomorphism ring are isomorphic?"

**Answer:** If $R$ is a commutative ring with $Pic(R) \neq 0$ the following holds for any linebundles $L,L':$

$$End_R(L) \cong L^*\otimes_R L \cong R \cong End_R(L').$$

Hence any pair of linebundles $L,L'$ have this property.

**Note:** For any linebundle $L$ it follows $End_R(L) \cong R$.

**Example:** If $K$ is any number field and $A$ the ring of integers in $K$, it follows $Pic(A)$ will be nontrivial in general. Hence choose any such $A$ with $Pic(A) \neq (0)$ and choose any nontrivial linebundle $L\neq A$. It follows

$$End_A(L) \cong A \cong End_A(A)$$

and $L \neq A$ are not isomorphic.,

Comment: Thanks! This example is a bit convoluted for me, do you know of something simpler?